# Help with a medical term for addiction to medicinal properties

Tags: single-word-requests, medical

I am looking for a word I had heard on a medical show ages ago, The Good Doctor to be specific, to use on my medical project in high school. The term referred to someone who had a sort of addiction to taking medications (not referring to illicit drugs, but prescribed medications). It sounded like something along the lines of Gardiobraediactic, Gardiovradiactic, or something similar.
If anyone could help me find this, it would be greatly appreciated :)

I don't believe the prefix is cardio due to it not having to do with the heart or flow of blood

When I had done previous searches of what I had heard, I had not pulled any results at all - save for drastic misspellings like Chiropractic. I had even gone back to searching for medical terms used in The Good Doctor but it was only showing simple words like necrosis, or even simpler ones like autism.

I had also searched for "medical term for addiction to medicine" however all it had pulled was drug and substance abuse.

Comment: All I can think of is *hypochondriac*. Some of them want attention, others want prescription drugs.

Comment: Most drug addictions and deaths (at least in the US) are attributed to legal prescription drugs. If you are talking about opioids you need to make it clear. Otherwise it sounds like yet another symptom of _Munchhausen's_.

Comment: We have a [medicalsciences.se] site that might be better to ask this question on.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a word referring to overuse of a specific drug, or a symptom caused by overuse? There are a lot of words such as salicylism for taking an excessive amount of aspirin, although I can't match up any to yours. The prefix sounds like the word would be Cardio-something, which would refer to symptoms affecting the heart.